# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.mycila.maven-license-plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, sonarqube

I am trying to create a Sonar plugin using java. For that purpose, I have created a java project and converted it to Maven project following this tutorial and added some functionalities to it-

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Writing+Custom+Rules+using+Java

My pom.xml looks like this now -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
</parent>


<groupId>org.sonar.samples</groupId>
<artifactId>java-custom-rules</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>sonar-plugin</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.plugin.version>3.8</java.plugin.version>
</properties>

<name>Java Custom Rules</name>
<description>Java Custom Rules</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-java-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${java.plugin.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-squid</artifactId>
        <version>${java.plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.sslr-squid-bridge</groupId>
        <artifactId>sslr-squid-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.sslr</groupId>
                <artifactId>sslr-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-checks-testkit</artifactId>
        <version>${java.plugin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.sslr</groupId>
        <artifactId>sslr-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.30</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <pluginClass>org.sonar.samples.java.MyJavaRulesPlugin</pluginClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                                    <version>4.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-jars</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.mycila.maven-license-plugin
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-license-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.9.0,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>check</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            -->
        </plugins> 
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

But, when I am doing clean package or clean compile, it is giving the error:
`Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.mycila.maven-license-plugin:maven-license-plugin:1.9.0:check (execution: enforce-license-headers, phase: validate)`

And, it shows the error at the line -

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>18</version>
    </parent>
```

Some, quick fixes are available -

1. Discover new m2e connection - which returns nothing.
2. Mark goal check as ignored in Eclipse build in Eclipse preferences.
3. Permanently mark goal check in pom.xml as ignored in Eclipse build.- This solves the compilation problem, but I am not exactly sure the post effects of it.

Any idea, what to do in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Why plugin `org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0` configuration is commented?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the error go away by running `mvn license:format` to add license headers to all your files. That's what the error is telling you - that the expected license headers aren't in place.

However, you should probably change your parent pom (not sure whether that will also remove the error).

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.sonarsource.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>24</version>
</parent>
```

is what's currently used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove unused whitespace from `gourpId`, `artifactId` and `versionRange` nodes:

```
<configuration>
    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
        <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>com.mycila.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.9.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                <action>
                    <ignore/>
                </action>
            </pluginExecution>
        </pluginExecutions>
    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
</configuration>
```

You can also set `versionRange` to `[0,)`